# Не получается получить параметры атрибутов Active Directory

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь получить данные из атрибутов учетной записи в Active Directory. С получением обычного текста нет проблем и он выводится:

```
string SamAccountName = directory.Properties["SamAccountName"][0].ToString();

ad_login.Text = SamAccountName;
```

Соответственно он правильно отдает в label имя пользователя. Но если пытаюсь получить например атрибут с длинным числом accountExpires (значение 9223372036854775807)...

```
LargeInteger expiry = directoryEntry.Properties["accountExpires"].Value as LargeInteger;

long int64Value = (long)((uint)(((long)expire.HightPart) << 32));

datat.Text = Convert.ToString(int64Value);
```

То он выдает: **0**.
Если убрать строчку

```
long int64Value = (long)((uint)(((long)expire.HightPart) << 32));
```

То он выдает:

```
System.__ComObject
```

Что я не так делаю?!

Comment: Возможно решение вашей проблемы находится [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6360284/convert-ldap-accountexpires-to-datetime-in-c-sharp).

Comment: @Rootware да, действительно ту УЗ которую я подгружаю не имеет срока просрочки, поэтому результат 0. НО если я открою этот атрибут напрямую в редакторе этой УЗ, он мне покажет значение: 9223372036854775807

Comment: Если вам принципиально работать через `long` то посмотрите [этот](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/ru/examples/-/LargeInteger/-/php-largeinteger-class-examples.html) вариант преобразования LargeInteger в Long. У вас возможно перепутаны или некорректно указаны представления при выборке высокой части числа.

Comment: Итоговый код скину завтра, если интересно, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел выход:

В строчку

```
long int64Value = (long)((uint)(((long)expire.HightPart) << 32));
```

Нужно было добавить еще  expire.LowPart